# Newest objects from the GAE datastore with JDO?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I have a 'Message' class in a Google App Engine application and I want to retrive the last(newest) ones from the datastore; like the 20 newest messages. It looks basic but I don't know how to create such a query with JDO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you'll have to store a timestamp on every `Message` entity. Then, when that's done:

```
public List<Person> get20NewestMessages() {
  Query q = new Query("Message")
  q.addSort("timestamp", SortDirection.DESCENDING);
  PreparedQuery pq = ds.prepare(q);
  return pq.asList(FetchOptions.Builder.withLimit(20));
}
```

**edit** As you pointed out, this uses the low-level datastore. Here's a JDO example to try out:

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(Message.class);
query.setOrdering("timestamp desc");
query.setRange(0, 20);
List<Message> messages = (List) query.execute();
```

(I haven't tested this, it may not work)

Comment: Your solution uses the low-level Java datastore API but it gave me all the elements I needed to do it with JDO. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If your entity already has a numeric ID field, then you could also use that instead of a timestamp -- i.e. fetch the 20 messages with the highest IDs.

Comment: An auto-incrementing numeric ID field is very inefficient, since it requires a read on every insert to find the current highest number. Using a timestamp is much better, it doesn't require knowing any information about other entities in the datastore.

Comment: @Todd IDs on App Engine are not guaranteed to be sequential, only unique. @Jason App Engine provides unique numeric IDs, without the inefficiency you describe.

Comment: @Nick Unique IDs, yes, but not auto-incrementing in a way that would allow you to get the N "newest" entities as @Todd described.

Comment: @Jason Yes, which is what the first part of my comment said. I'm just pointing out that your statement about using IDs being inefficient is factually inaccuate when it comes to App Engine's counters.

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.jdo.PersistenceManager;
import javax.jdo.Query;
import javax.jdo.Transaction;
...

public List<Message> get20NewestMessages() {
    PersistenceManager pm = PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();      
    Query q = pm.newQuery(Message.class);
    q.setOrdering("timestamp desc");
    q.setRange(0, 20);
    List<Message> messages = (List<Message>) q.execute();
    return messages;
}
```